# Trouble creating a hover tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, data-visualization

I was trying to do the FreeCodeCamp Data Visualisation project and I am stuck on creating a hover tooltip that follows the cursor

Here is my entire code: https://github.com/Ruchirich/barchart

I did make a hover tooltip but the `left` style attribute of it keeps changing when the screen size changes and I don't know how to keep it fixed

If I use either pageX or clientX, it changes according to screen size. I tried using `this.getScreenCTM()` but it throws off an error saying "It is not a function"

This is the mouseover function.

````
.on('mouseover', (item, index) => {
            let parsed = new Date(item[0])
            let dateString = `${parsed.getFullYear()} - ${monthNames[parsed.getMonth()]}`
            var posX = d3.event.clientX;
            

            tooltip.style('top', '-180px')
                    .style('left', (posX - 450) + 'px')
                    .style('white-space', 'pre')

            tooltip.transition()
                   .style('visibility', 'visible')    

            document.querySelector('#tooltip').setAttribute('data-date', item[0])
            document.querySelector('#tooltip').textContent = "$" + `${item [1]} Billions\r\n  ${dateString}`
        }) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I build something like this before, it was really fun doing it.

The best way is to use `getBoundingClientRect` when working with position.

Here is a small example.

```js
var timer = null;
$(".tip").on("mouseover", function(){
  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(()=> {
  var item = $(this)
  var toolTip = $("<tooltip>"+item.attr("tip") +"</tooltip>");
  var pos =this.getBoundingClientRect();
  toolTip.attr("style", `
    position: fixed;
    top: ${pos.top + 30}px;
    left: ${pos.left + (pos.width / 2)}px; 
  `);
  $("body").append(toolTip)
  }, 500);
})

$(".tip").on("mouseout", function(e){
  clearTimeout(timer)
  if (e.target.tagName != "tooltip")
    $("tooltip").remove();
})
```

```css
tooltip{
border:1px solid #CCC;
padding:5px;
}
p{
   margin:auto;
   width:150px;
   position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="tip" tip="This is an exmaple tooltip">
  hoverme for 500ms
<p>
```

Comment: It throws off this error :(  `Uncaught TypeError: this.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

Comment: Well its working for me here, I cant see any error

Comment: @Ruchira Choudhary, use `function()` not arrow notation: 'this' will not be the element otherwise, hence your error and why Alen does not see one.

Comment: ohhh thanks a lot for pointing that out @AndrewReid  it finally works

Comment: and thank you so so much @Alen.Toma ! apparently, It was a mistake on my end

Comment: np, glad I could help. Don't forget to make this as answer if it really solve your problem.